# Need clarification on "@objc class" in Swift

Tags: swift, class, protocols, option-type

I understand what the "@objc" attribute does for protocols. What I don't understand is why it is added to classes, such as in the following example:

```
@objc protocol CounterDataSource {
    optional func incrementForCount(count: Int) -> Int
    optional var fixedIncrement: Int { get }
}

@objc class Counter {
    var count = 0
    var dataSource: CounterDataSource?
    func increment() {
        if let amount = dataSource?.incrementForCount?(count) {
            count += amount
        } else if let amount = dataSource?.fixedIncrement {
            count += amount
        }
    }
}
```

Here is what it states on Apple's Swift documentation:

> Note also that @objc protocols can be adopted only by classes, and not by structures or enumerations. If you mark your protocol as @objc in order to specify optional requirements, you will only be able to apply that protocol to class types.

There is no explanation of "@objc class..", only "@objc protocol".

Answer (score 1):

On [this page](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Attributes.html), it says

> If you apply the `objc` attribute to a class or protocol, it’s implicitly applied to the members of that class or protocol. The compiler also implicitly adds the `objc` attribute to a class that inherits from another class marked with the `objc` attribute. Protocols marked with the `objc` attribute can’t inherit from protocols that aren’t.

So, the difference is that it applies implicitly to all members. Also, you'll be prevented from adding `@objc` to a generic class.

Comment: This explains a lot, but I am still curious for the purpose of it. It seems it is to expose it to the objective-c runtime, but why would I want that if I am coding in swift?

Comment: Though Swift is great, it's really valuable to be able to call/access Swift classes and types from Obj-C code.

Answer (score 1):

`@objc` on class declarations means the annotated class will be exposed to the Objective-C runtime. There are other implicit differences though, but I think this is the most important one.

You can try to omit the annotation from a pure Swift class (not a subclass of NSObject), then you are unable to use this class in Objective-C code (it won't appears in the genrated header file used by your Objective-C code).

**Note** that any classes inheriting `NSObject` or any of its subclasses will automatically(implicitly) be marked `@objc`. So it does not make sense to explicitly mark say a subclass of `UIViewController` as `@objc`, because the Swift compiler does it for you.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation :). My second question is, why would I need to expose my class to Objective-C? is it because I am conforming to an "@objc protocol"?

Comment: If you want to mix Swift and Objective-C code in the same project, you have to do so. If you write pure Swift applications, you don't have to mark any class declarations `@objc`. Under the hood, your classes are automatically marked `@objc` if they subclass any in the Cocoa Touch framework. The framework is written in Objective-C. Please refer to the offcial book *Using Swift with Cocoa and Objective-C*

Comment: "@objc on class declarations means the annotated class will be exposed to the Objective-C runtime." What do you mean by "exposed to the Objective-C runtime"? How is a non-`@objc` class not "exposed to the Objective-C runtime"?

Comment: Among others, it simply allows you to instantiate Swift classes and call Swift method from Objective-C code.

Comment: @Fujia: Please use `@` when responding to comments. When you say "call Swift method from Objective-C code", you mean compile-time, not runtime.

Comment: @newacct Sorry I didn't notice you are not the OP. There is no conception of "call a method at compile-time". Code is written by you with an editor, compiled by a compiler, and eventually executed by the hardware in a environment called "run-time" (potentially provided by the OS).

Comment: @Fujia: You said that non-`@objc` classes are not "exposed to the Objective-C runtime". But you can take a non-`@objc` class or its instance in Swift, pass the object into Objective-C code, and use that class or instance with the Objective-C runtime like any other class or instance. Although non-`@objc` methods won't be exposed to the Objective-C runtime, the class itself is exposed to the Objective-C runtime, and you *can* call certain Objective-C methods on this class object and its instances at runtime, like `alloc`, `init`, `equalTo:`, `description`, `isKindOfClass:`, etc.

Comment: @newacct That's because the class mentioned is a subclass of the Cocoa framework which inherits from NSObject. Swift mark NSObject subclasses as '@objc' automatically.

Comment: @Fujia: No, it isn't. I specifically said "non-`@objc`" class.