# How do I initialize this protocol in iOS?

Tags: ios, swift, oop

This is the [protocol](https://tokbox.com/developer/sdks/ios/reference/Protocols/OTVideoCaptureConsumer.html).

This is currently how I'm using it. However, it crashes when I try to access it, because I'm not initializing it right.

```
import Foundation
import OpenTok
import GPUImage

class FilteredPublisher:  OTPublisherKit, OTVideoCapture, GPUImageVideoCameraDelegate {
    weak var videoCaptureConsumer: OTVideoCaptureConsumer!  // Is this right?

    let imageHeight = 480
    let imageWidth = 640
    var videoCamera: GPUImageVideoCamera?
    var videoFrame = OTVideoFrame()
    var view = GPUImageView()

    override init() {
        super.init()
    }

    override init!(delegate: OTPublisherKitDelegate!) {
        super.init(delegate: delegate)
    }

    override init!(delegate: OTPublisherKitDelegate!, name: String!, audioTrack: Bool, videoTrack: Bool) {
        super.init(delegate: delegate, name: name, audioTrack: audioTrack, videoTrack: videoTrack)
    }

    override init!(delegate: OTPublisherKitDelegate!, name: String!){
        super.init(delegate: delegate, name: name)

        self.view = GPUImageView(frame: CGRectMake(0,0,1,1))
        self.videoCapture = self

        let format = OTVideoFormat()
        format.pixelFormat = OTPixelFormat.NV12
        format.imageWidth = UInt32(imageWidth)
        format.imageHeight = UInt32(imageHeight)
        self.videoFrame = OTVideoFrame(format: format)
    }


    func willOutputSampleBuffer(sampleBuffer: CMSampleBuffer!) {
        let imageBuffer = CMSampleBufferGetImageBuffer(sampleBuffer)
        CVPixelBufferLockBaseAddress(imageBuffer!, 0)
        videoFrame?.clearPlanes()


        for var i = 0 ; i < CVPixelBufferGetPlaneCount(imageBuffer!); ++i {
            videoFrame?.planes.addPointer(CVPixelBufferGetBaseAddressOfPlane(imageBuffer!, i))
        }
        videoFrame?.orientation = OTVideoOrientation.Left

        videoCaptureConsumer.consumeFrame(videoFrame) //this crashes the app
        CVPixelBufferUnlockBaseAddress(imageBuffer!, 0)
    }
}
```

When I run my app, everything builds. However, it crashes on this line: `videoCaptureConsumer.consumeFrame(videoFrame)`

Is it because I'm not initializing `videoCaptureConsumer` correctly?  `OTVideoCaptureConsumer` doesn't have an `init()`, so I'm not sure what to do.

[This](https://github.com/felixchan/opentok-gpuimage-filters/blob/master/HelloWorld/FilteredPublisher.swift) is my file .  [This](https://github.com/JayTokBox/TokBoxGPUImage/blob/master/TokBoxGPUImage/TokBoxGPUImagePublisher.m) is the Objective-C version that I translated from.

Comment: `videoCaptureConsumer` seems to be set via the `OTVideoCapture ` protocol, which sounds like objective-c dynamism. Could a well placed `@objc` help? Maybe on the class?

Comment: I think it makes your swift code visible to the objective-c runtime: http://stackoverflow.com/q/32020741/22147

Comment: Provide the code where you set the variable `videoCaptureConsumer`. And does that code ensure that the object stays alive? Because this class will not ensure that... I see in the link you provide that you removed the `weak` keyword but nothing in the code assigns anything to the variable.

Answer (score 0):

This is an implictly unwrapped optional:

```
weak var videoCaptureConsumer: OTVideoCaptureConsumer!
```

What you're basically saying here as the programmer is that anywhere in the code that you choose to call a method on this object, the object will not be nil. If you call a method on this object anywhere and the object happens to be nil, then your app will crash. Implicitly, you're saying that it's a bug if you're trying to call a method on `videoCaptureConsumer` and it is nil.

If you're getting a crash when calling `consumeFrame:`, these are the points of failure, in order of occurrence:

1. The `videoCaptureConsumer` property is not being set anywhere. This entails initializing an object which implements the `OTVideoCaptureConsumer` protocol.
2. The object that is being set is getting deallocated before the call to `consumeFrame:`. This happens if no one else is holding a reference to the object.
3. The object is still around, but it doesn't implement the method `consumeFrame:`, or the method signature is wrong (e.g. it doesn't accept an input when it should).
4. The object's implementation of `consumeFrame:` contains a bug.

Comment: It seems that it's crashing on ```consumeFrame```.  videoCaptureConsumer is not nil.

Comment: Apologies, but I don't understand how you came to this conclusion. You don't initialize ```OTVideoCaptureConsumer``` directly, you initialize an object that implements the ```OTVideoCaptureConsumer``` protocol, where is that happening?